# Redirect user to custom login page when using Azure AD

Tags: c#, active-directory, asp.net-identity, owin, azure-active-directory

I'm using the following code example to plug in Azure AD login to my application (https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet).

I'm finding that the code works just fine however I want to have to ability to redirect a user to a custom login page if the user hasn't logged in yet or their session has expired. I'm struggling however to get this to work and was wondering if this is indeed possible at all?

Is it by design that the user is always redirected to the Microsoft Login page for Azure AD rather than your own custom page or is there a setting I've missed?

I've amended the supplied code in `FilterConfig.cs` to enable the Authorize filter attribute:

```
filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

I've also added the following to `web.config` but to no effect:

```
<authorization>
<allow users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Within the `Startup.Auth.cs` file I cannot see any changes that are possible to `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` to allow me to set up a generic login page as I may possibly do with cookies based auth.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some re going over the code I've found the solution to my issue.

Within `Startup.Auth.cs`:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
   LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
   new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
      ClientId = clientId,
      Authority = authority,
      PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
      AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive
});
```

It's the inclusion of the `AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive` line which seems to stop OpenIdConnectAuth from performing the automatic 302 redirect to the AAD login pages.

Comment: @BenV combining your suggestion of using AAD premium for custom AAD login screen with the above I think this is a far more preferable approach to having a somewhat customised login flow.

Comment: If I could upvote this answer more than once, I would.

Comment: Kevin i  upvoted  for you as well :) it solved my problem. thanks @Choms79

Comment: Fixed it for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Azure AD is your identity provider, you can [Customize the login page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn532270.aspx), but you have to be running [Azure AD Premium](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn532272.aspx) to do so.

Comment: Thanks for this @BenV, I was hoping that I could have complete control within my app and present a custom login page whenever authorisation was needed i.e. http://<my domain>/Account/Login. I'm guessing you can't because that defeats the purpose of AD Premium.

Comment: The idea is that instead of taking on the responsibility for **securely** collecting and transporting the users credentials yourself, you can delegate this responsibility to AAD.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe what I'm looking for...

- non-interactive authentication in a native client
  (https://github.com/AzureADSamples/NativeClient-Headless-DotNet)

This sample allows a user to login to Azure AD without the need to use Azure AD's native browser based logins.

I understand this is somewhat considered an anti pattern as I'll be forgoing Azure's built in mechanisms for handling multi factor auth, password resets etc. but I'll retain full control of the experience.

==== Edit ====
This isn't the way I want to go as I'll be stripping out a lot of what AAD offers out the box. In essence I'd like to keep AAD's control flows but I just want to have the ability to control what page a user lands on when a user isn't logged in.

Currently the flow is:
Not authorised -> 302 redirect -> AAD login

I'd like:
Not authorised -> 302 redirect -> Self hosted login required page -> User login button press -> 302 redirect -> AAD login

Its this flow I can't seem to work out.

Comment: This is also misusing the OAuth protocol (which is intended for delegated authorization) for authentication, which [some say](http://www.thread-safe.com/2012/01/problem-with-oauth-for-authentication.html) opens some security holes.  But yes, it is technically possible and you do retain full control of the UX.