# Minimum Requirements To Use MSAL For Azure B2C

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms, asp.net-identity, owin

I am tasked with implementing Azure B2C into an existing ASP.Net Web Forms application as a second form of signing in. It currently uses forms authentication authenticating with username/password against an established series of Sql Server database tables.

Can MSAL library be used with Form Authentication?

We have existing user tables that will need to be used as they are used by other applications and will not be able to be updated.

Please let me know if you need more details to provide a better answer.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: MSAL library helps you to authenticate with Azure AD, or Azure B2C [so including social accounts], I don't think you can use it for doing forms authentication[to make it to verify against your app DB tables].

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to add azure ad b2c authentication to your existing application which have form authentication.

***AFAIK, in our web application we can not pass the `username/password` directly to Azure AD for authentication.***

To use Azure AD along with form based authentication based on SQL DB stored username and password we will have to set the authentication mode to `none` in `web.config`.
And create a new Authorization filter to redirect the users who are unauthorized to that form based login page.

Also Users can log in using OAuth 2.0 with credentials from an external authentication source like Facebook, Twitter, LinkedIn, Microsoft, or Google.

For complete setup please refer this [***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) & [***SO THREAD***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517518/how-to-use-both-internal-forms-authenticationas-well-as-azure-ad-authentication)