# Is there a way to redirect a user to a custom Not Authorized Page?

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory

I am looking into the role based authorization using azure ad.  I understand for the most part how to create and assign roles inside of the project manifest.  What I am wondering is how can I redirect a user to a custom "Not Authorized" page if they are not authorized to view that specific page and or method.  Right now all that happens when a user is not authorized is they get redirected to the Microsoft login screen and says that "We couldn't sign you in.  Please try again."

I've tried different options in the project manifest but I haven't had any success with that.

If a user is not authorized I want to redirect them to a custom "Not Authorized" page.

Comment: Possible answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517925/redirect-user-to-custom-login-page-when-using-azure-ad?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for this issue is to use the AuthenticationMode.Passive so that it will not redirect to AAD login pages

You have to write a following code in your Startup.Auth.cs

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
   LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
   new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
      ClientId = clientId,
      Authority = authority,
      PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
      AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive
});
```

It is the `AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Passive` which stop OpenIdConnectAuth from performing the automatic 302 redirect to the AAD login pages.

Hope it helps.